# How to detect if mouse is touching monitor bound

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I made myself a draggable form with the border property set to none. I can drag the form by holding the left mouse button on a panel. Now I need to check if the mouse is touching a border of the monitor. I've tried multiple solutions but none of them seem to work. Everytime my mouse touches the North-West of my monitor it thinks it touches the North-East. Is there a good way to check if my mouse is touching a border?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code...

Comment: why'd you need code? I just need a way to detect if my mouse is nearing a bound of the monitor @ZoharPeled

Comment: The short list 1. You should show your efforts when writing a question in SO. 2. Your code might just have a typo you are missing, sometimes it just needs a fresh set of eyes to look at it. 3. Without the code, your question might get voted as off-topic: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: Ah okay thank you. Next time I'll keep that in mind. I got it to work using Screen.FromPoint(Form1.MousePosition);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the absolute position of the cusor with

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```

Then you can check the position in a loop of another thread and raise an event when it is near a border.

{X=0,Y=0} is upper left corner.